# How can i update existing ionic app with new version?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i am working on a template from code pen,the link is given below.

```
"http://codepen.io/fairupoyil/pen/oXrXjX?editors=100"
```

its version is low so i updated the js file with new version but bow i am not getting the menu icon and tab icon the app is not working properly.

Comment: Js file is not the only one. You have dependencies and such that have to be updated as well. [Link from the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/install.html)

Answer (score 2):

so navigate to your project directory in the command line, then type

```
ionic lib update
```

this will update the ionic library to the newest version.